# Very slow EF Core with Azure Functions when try block is added

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I have the main trigger HTTP (Azure Function) code here that goes to different functions to get data and builds it up into a JSON response and sends a JSON to postman via a try block :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData req)
        {

        try
        {
            var GetCuurency = await GetCurrencyAsync();
            var GetUnderwriters = await GetUnderWritersAsync();
            var GetSubmissionType = await GetSubmissionsTypes();
            var dynamicOptions = new
            {
                Underwriter = GetUnderwriters,
                Currency = GetCuurency,
                Submission_Type = GetSubmissionType
            };

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(dynamicOptions);


            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = new
            {
                Error = ex.Message
            };

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(error, response.StatusCode);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

So the awaits at the top of the try goes a function that calls a ef core function. And it returns data via a custom DTO model - like below :

```
public async Task<List<DTO.Currency_DTO>> GetCurrencyAsync()
        { 
             
                return await _ripple_primary_context.RipplCurrencies.Select(p => new DTO.Currency_DTO
                {
                    currency_id = p.CurrencyId,
                    currency_name = p.CurrencyName,
                    currency_alpha_code = p.CurrencyAlphaCode

                    }).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
  

        }
```

As you can see i have put them all in a await and performed them all async. the three methods are generally the same just targeting different tables.

if i dont put the try method in , I get the results back in 3 secs (locally) so thats reasonable. but if i put the try block in and for example change the sql server name to be wrong then the error comes but it takes around 30 seconds which is terrible. How can i optmise this code so the error comes back much quicker.

Considered doing only one call to SQL (i.e only one method but then i have problems with multiple dto's.

Bit confused how to optimise this - any ideas would be amazing.

Comment: First step would be to identify the bottleneck(s). And not by assumption but by measurement.

Comment: The delay is caused by the *error*, not handling the error. 30 seconds sounds like a connection timeout. With `catch` you can log the error at least. Without it, your application will crash

Comment: Where are you logging the error? If you didn't notice that the message is about a timeout, does your logging work *at all*? Why invent your own logging instead of using eg ILogger with a console and a remote service sink like App Insights? This way if the remote service fails you'll still get the console logs

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in how you are testing it, not in the code you are testing. There is nothing in your code that will cause a 30 second delay. The delay is occurring when you test it by changing the name of SQL Server because it is taking 30 seconds to time out when it attempts to connect to a non-existent instance of SQL Server.

Comment: A  more interesting question is why the error message went unnoticed?

Comment: Thanks Peter - good work !! I can see on my connection string it has the timeout of 30... makes sense....